# PHP Datetime with combined modifier value (last day of this month)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to create `Datetime` *3 days after last day of this month* based on date from constructor with this code:

`(new Datetime('2019-01-01'))->modify('last day of this month, +3 days')->format('Y-m-d')`

so expected output is `2019-02-03` but `2019-01-31` is given.

Consider this code works like charm

`(new Datetime('2019-01-01'))->modify('+1 days, +3 days')->format('Y-m-d')`

expected: `2019-01-05` given: `2019-01-05`

and this also works as well:

`(new Datetime('2019-01-01'))->modify('last day of this month, +3 hours')->format('Y-m-d H')`

expected: `2019-01-31 03` given `2019-01-31 03`

**Question**: It's a bug or feature? Or maybe using `last day of this month` blocks next `days` modifications?

Comment: you can try to use `->modify('last day of this month')->modify('+3 days')`

Comment: last day is 31st and you are using `H` to get +3 hours. are u assuming, what is your expectation?

Comment: +3 hours - defines the timezone, so it's not a bug. the modify expects the timezone after you write the day

Comment: @Sergej `->modify('last day of this month')->modify('+3 days')` works, question is why `->modify('last day of this month, +3 days')` don't work. `modify('+1 days, +3 days')` works as expected. Why timezone in involved? 
`new Datetime('2019-01-01')` is `"2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000"` in your default timezone

Comment: modify('+1 days, +3 days') is same kind of rule this is adding a days in given date. and first rule is not same kind of rule that are two diffrent operation of the date. first find the last day and then need to add day into it. so it not a bug. the modify function is design like this way.

Comment: You can be adding the hours because that is the same starting point from the 12 midnight for all the date. so it will be work with any next date also. to resolve that limitation we need to separate the operation with a write-down two times modify() as per the @Sergej first answer.

Comment: I believe the question here is not asking how to accomplish the end result, but rather whether or not this is a bug / feature. I would say this is the lack of a feature before I called it a bug. The parser itself seems incapable of calculating  day modifiers when last of or first of is used in the date modifier for a singular statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is noted in the documentation for [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) where it says:

> Note that expressions such as “last day of” and “first day of” imply a
>   day of a month, not, for example of the year or week.
>
> So, expressions, such as “first day of this year” will give the first
>   day of this month, with no apparent regard for the year.
>
> As powerful as the parser is, it can lead to disappointing or
>   confusing results.

It is likely that it is taking priority of the phrase "Last day of" and ignoring the rest of the day statement, even though it's comma separated. As for why it is parsing the time, is it likely parses time effects first, then looks for day effects. [The source-code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re) for the functionality can be investigated deeper as to why this is happening. One thing to note is how the first and last day phrases are scanned

```
firstdayof | lastdayof
{
    DEBUG_OUTPUT("firstdayof | lastdayof");
    TIMELIB_INIT;
    TIMELIB_HAVE_RELATIVE();

    /* skip "last day of" or "first day of" */
    if (*ptr == 'l' || *ptr == 'L') {
        s->time->relative.first_last_day_of = TIMELIB_SPECIAL_LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH;
    } else {
        s->time->relative.first_last_day_of = TIMELIB_SPECIAL_FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH;
    }

    TIMELIB_DEINIT;
    return TIMELIB_LF_DAY_OF_MONTH;
}
```

The pointer only looks at whether or not there's an l or L so it seems to be cutting some corners there.